# Using dict for setting plotly Dash Slider marks results in syntax error

Tags: plotly-dash

I'm building a dashboard based on plotly Dash. One of the dcc is a Slider. If I want to show marks on the slider that are within a certain range of numbers, then this works just fine:

```
dcc.Slider(min=-10, max=20, step=1, value=0, marks={i: str(i) for i in range(-10, 20)})
```

But Dash documentation prefers to use dict notation. But if I do this:

```
dcc.Slider(min=-10, max=20, step=1, value=0, marks=dict(i = str(i) for i in range(-10,20)))
```

then I receive a Syntax Error

How can I implement this functionality using dict notation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`dict()` can take in a list of key-value pairs. So you can do a list-comprehension inside your dict notation:

```
dcc.Slider(min=-10, max=20, step=1, value=0, marks=dict([(i,str(i)) for i in range(-10,20)]))
```

However I would still prefer the dict literal way, just for the slightly better readability and operation.

Comment: Casting to list before creating the `dict()` is not necessary; You can just `dict((i,str(i)) for i in range(-10,20))`

Comment: Yes, I agree in this case literal notation looks cleaner.